# KeyError when testing DRF model with custom create action

Tags: python, testing, django-rest-framework

Many tests started to fail after adding custom `create` method to a model. Everything was fine when only 'stage 1' was in action, but after adding 'stage 2': creation of a GitLab project via GL's API, many tests failed.

The model is defined this way:

```py
class CarModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = CarModel.objects.all()
   serializer_class = CarModelSerializer
   lookup_field = 'model_id'

   def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      ## stage 1:
      serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
      serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
      serializer.save()

      ## stage 2:
      proj_name = str(serializer.data['model_id']) + str(serializer.data['name']).replace(' ', '_')
      proj_desc = str(serializer.data['name']) + ' Project'

      req_headers = {
                     'content-type': 'application/json',
                     'PRIVATE-TOKEN': settings.REPOSITORY_TOKEN
      }
      req_body = {
                  "name": proj_name,
                  "namespace_id": 10,
                  "description": proj_desc
      }

      repository_url = 'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/'
      res = requests.post(repository_url, json.dumps(req_body), headers=req_headers)
      response = res.json()
      response_msg = {
         "message": "Model added to database. Project created in GitLab.",
         "id": response["id"], ########### KeyError: 'id'
         "name": response["name"],
         "name_with_namespace": response["name_with_namespace"],
         "ssh_url_to_repo": response["ssh_url_to_repo"],
         "http_url_to_repo": response["http_url_to_repo"],
         "web_url": response["web_url"]
      }

      return Response(response_msg, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Example test:

```py
class CarModelTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()

    def test_create_correct_car_model(self):
        """Test creating valid Car Model instance."""
        payload = {
            "model_id": "12/34/5678-9",
            "name": "Test Model",
            "active": True
            }

        res = self.client.post(CAR_MODELS_URL, payload)

        models = CarModel.objects.all()
        serializer = CarModelSerializer(models, many=True)

        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        print(json.dumps(serializer.data))
        self.assertEqual("Model added to database. Project created in GitLab.",
                            json.dumps(serializer.data[0]["message"]))
```

Test reports point out the line with `"id": response["id"]` as the failing one (not sure if test run is terminated at this point and other ones are not reported, or simply only this entry is failing).

Manual testing works fine, model gets created in database and a new project appears in GitLab.

What should I do to overcome this failure?

Comment: What is the content  of  the response body return from Gitlab API after creating the project? Since there isn't documentation on the response schema from the API docs, print and inspect the response structure. That should guide which fields are accessible in the response

Comment: Did you mean the actual response from GitLab right after attempting to create the project? If so, there's none, even after setting verbosity of the test run to the max. level (3). Desired and correct response should be formatted as in `response_msg` in the markup.

Comment: Do you realise that you are dependent on the Gitlab site while running your tests. Meaning that running the tests twice will lead to different results because.... the project will exists already for the second run....

Comment: That's the point! Please post it as an answer (please include some basic check like: `if "id" in response: ...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> after adding 'stage 2': creation of a GitLab project via GL's API, many tests failed.

The testing already created a project and project ID; any further tests will fail because the project already exists.
To check if it exists, do `GET /users/:user_id/projects` or any similar request and check for the name(or whatever) of the project you wan to create in the response.
It looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "description": null,
    "default_branch": "master",
    "visibility": "private",
    "ssh_url_to_repo": "git@example.com:diaspora/diaspora-client.git",
    "http_url_to_repo": "http://example.com/diaspora/diaspora-client.git",
    "web_url": "http://example.com/diaspora/diaspora-client",
    "readme_url": "http://example.com/diaspora/diaspora-client/blob/master/README.md",
    "tag_list": [
      "example",
      "disapora client"
    ],
    "owner": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Diaspora",
      "created_at": "2013-09-30T13:46:02Z"
    },
    "name": "Diaspora Client",
    "name_with_namespace": "Diaspora / Diaspora Client",
    "path": "diaspora-client",
    "path_with_namespace": "diaspora/diaspora-client",
    "issues_enabled": true,
    "open_issues_count": 1,
    "merge_requests_enabled": true,
    "jobs_enabled": true,
    "wiki_enabled": true,
    "snippets_enabled": false,
    "can_create_merge_request_in": true,
    "resolve_outdated_diff_discussions": false,
    "container_registry_enabled": false,
    "created_at": "2013-09-30T13:46:02Z",
    "last_activity_at": "2013-09-30T13:46:02Z",
    "creator_id": 3,
    "namespace": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Diaspora",
      "path": "diaspora",
      "kind": "group",
      "full_path": "diaspora"
    },
    "import_status": "none",
    "archived": false,
    "avatar_url": "http://example.com/uploads/project/avatar/4/uploads/avatar.png",
    "shared_runners_enabled": true,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "star_count": 0,
    "runners_token": "b8547b1dc37721d05889db52fa2f02",
    "ci_default_git_depth": 50,
    "public_jobs": true,
    "shared_with_groups": [],
    "only_allow_merge_if_pipeline_succeeds": false,
    "only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved": false,
    "remove_source_branch_after_merge": false,
    "request_access_enabled": false,
    "merge_method": "merge",
    "autoclose_referenced_issues": true,
    "suggestion_commit_message": null,
    "marked_for_deletion_at": "2020-04-03", // to be deprecated in GitLab 13.0 in favor of marked_for_deletion_on
    "marked_for_deletion_on": "2020-04-03",
    "statistics": {
      "commit_count": 37,
      "storage_size": 1038090,
      "repository_size": 1038090,
      "wiki_size" : 0,
      "lfs_objects_size": 0,
      "job_artifacts_size": 0,
      "packages_size": 0
    },
    "_links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/api/v4/projects",
      "issues": "http://example.com/api/v4/projects/1/issues",
      "merge_requests": "http://example.com/api/v4/projects/1/merge_requests",
      "repo_branches": "http://example.com/api/v4/projects/1/repository_branches",
      "labels": "http://example.com/api/v4/projects/1/labels",
      "events": "http://example.com/api/v4/projects/1/events",
      "members": "http://example.com/api/v4/projects/1/members"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "description": null,
    "default_branch": "master",
    "visibility": "private",
    "ssh_url_to_repo": "git@example.com:brightbox/puppet.git",
    "http_url_to_repo": "http://example.com/brightbox/puppet.git",
    "web_url": "http://example.com/brightbox/puppet",
    "readme_url": "http://example.com/brightbox/puppet/blob/master/README.md",
    "tag_list": [
      "example",
      "puppet"
    ],
    "owner": {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Brightbox",
      "created_at": "2013-09-30T13:46:02Z"
    },
    "name": "Puppet",
    "name_with_namespace": "Brightbox / Puppet",
    "path": "puppet",
    "path_with_namespace": "brightbox/puppet",
    "issues_enabled": true,
    "open_issues_count": 1,
    "merge_requests_enabled": true,
    "jobs_enabled": true,
    "wiki_enabled": true,
    "snippets_enabled": false,
    "can_create_merge_request_in": true,
    "resolve_outdated_diff_discussions": false,
    "container_registry_enabled": false,
    "created_at": "2013-09-30T13:46:02Z",
    "last_activity_at": "2013-09-30T13:46:02Z",
    "creator_id": 3,
    "namespace": {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Brightbox",
      "path": "brightbox",
      "kind": "group",
      "full_path": "brightbox"
    },
    "import_status": "none",
    "import_error": null,
    "permissions": {
      "project_access": {
        "access_level": 10,
        "notification_level": 3
      },
      "group_access": {
        "access_level": 50,
        "notification_level": 3
      }
    },
    "archived": false,
    "avatar_url": null,
    "shared_runners_enabled": true,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "star_count": 0,
    "runners_token": "b8547b1dc37721d05889db52fa2f02",
    "ci_default_git_depth": 0,
    "public_jobs": true,
    "shared_with_groups": [],
    "only_allow_merge_if_pipeline_succeeds": false,
    "only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved": false,
    "remove_source_branch_after_merge": false,
    "request_access_enabled": false,
    "merge_method": "merge",
    "auto_devops_enabled": true,
    "auto_devops_deploy_strategy": "continuous",
    "repository_storage": "default",
    "approvals_before_merge": 0,
    "mirror": false,
    "mirror_user_id": 45,
    "mirror_trigger_builds": false,
    "only_mirror_protected_branches": false,
    "mirror_overwrites_diverged_branches": false,
    "external_authorization_classification_label": null,
    "packages_enabled": true,
    "service_desk_enabled": false,
    "service_desk_address": null,
    "autoclose_referenced_issues": true,
    "suggestion_commit_message": null,
    "statistics": {
      "commit_count": 12,
      "storage_size": 2066080,
      "repository_size": 2066080,
      "wiki_size" : 0,
      "lfs_objects_size": 0,
      "job_artifacts_size": 0,
      "packages_size": 0
    },
    "_links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/api/v4/projects",
      "issues": "http://example.com/api/v4/projects/1/issues",
      "merge_requests": "http://example.com/api/v4/projects/1/merge_requests",
      "repo_branches": "http://example.com/api/v4/projects/1/repository_branches",
      "labels": "http://example.com/api/v4/projects/1/labels",
      "events": "http://example.com/api/v4/projects/1/events",
      "members": "http://example.com/api/v4/projects/1/members"
    }
  }
]
```

I'd also recommend using [python-gitlab](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). It has many features that make these things easier.

Comment: I'll also add, that printing `response` from the original markup reveals the message about existing repository.

Comment: @AbreQueVoy If you're referring to the first POST request, you'd be correct! It's  unnecessary after the first time, though. Using the GET request I'd mentioned (or any similar ones) is more appropriate for subsequent meta data queries. Have you fixed the issue? If not, I'll help you as much as I can.

Comment: Printing `response` helps to debug tests. And adding `if "id" in response: (...) else: (...)` clause prevents errors or handles exceptions gracefully. In my case, I return status code 204: No Content (probably something better can be found to describe the situation, however tests get processed in a valid way). And yes, the issue is fixed, thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh yeah, it's ok for testing. I think you're getting the corect status code. edit: Take a look at this: https://httpstatuses.com/204 ; there is even a related gitlab issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/62872 Glad I could help, you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

your issue is with this line:

```
res = requests.post(repository_url, json.dumps(req_body), headers=req_headers)
```

change it to:

```
res = requests.post(repository_url, json=req_body, headers=req_headers)
```

> Note that you don't have to encode the request JSON data